# How to make server respond faster on First Byte?

Tags: linux, performance, webserver, dedicated

My website has seen ever decreasing traffic, so I've been working to increase speed and usability. On WebPageTest.org I've worked most of my grades up but **First Byte** is still horrible.

```
F First Byte Time
A Keep-alive Enabled
A Compress Transfer
A Compress Images
A Progressive JPEGs
B Cache static 

First Byte Time (back-end processing): 0/100

1081 ms First Byte Time
90 ms Target First Byte Time
```

I use the Rackspace Cloud Server system,

- CentOS 6.4 2gig of Ram 80 gig harddrive,
- Next Generation Server
- Linux 2.6.32-358.18.1.el6.x86_64
- Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
- MySQL 5.1.69
- PHP: 5.3.3 / Zend: 2.3.0

Website system Tomatocart Shopping Cart.

Any help would be much appreciated.

---

Traceroute #1 to 198.61.171.121

Hop    Time (ms)   IP Address  FQDN

1. 0.855 - 199.193.244.67
2. 0.405 - 184.105.250.41 - gige-g2-14.core1.mci3.he.net
3. 15.321 - 184.105.222.117 - 10gigabitethernet1-4.core1.chi1.he.net
4. 12.737 - 206.223.119.14 - bbr1.ord1.rackspace.NET
5. 14.198 - 184.106.126.144 - corea.ord1.rackspace.net
6. 14.597 - 50.56.6.129 - corea-core5.ord1.rackspace.net
7. 13.915 - 50.56.6.111 - core5-aggr1501a-1.ord1.rackspace.net
8. 16.538 - 198.61.171.121 - mail.aboveallhousplans.com

---

@JXH's advise I did a packet capture and analyzed it using wireshark.
during a hit and leave visit to the site I got

6 lines of BAD TCP happening at about lines 28-33 
warning that I have TCP Retransmission and TCP Dup ACK... 
2 of each of these warnings 3 times.

Under the expanded panel viewing a 
Retransmission/ TCP analysis flags - "retransmission suspected" "security level NOTE" RTO of 1.19 seconds.

Under the expanded panel viewing 
DCP Dup ACK/ TCP analysis flags - Duplicate ACK" "security level NOTE" RTT of 0.09 seconds.

This is all gibberish to me...

---

I don't know if this is wise to do or not, but I've uploaded my packet capture dump file.

If anyone cares to take a look at my flags and let me know what they think.

---

I wonder if the retransmission warnings are saying that the HTTP file is sending duplicate information? I have a few things in twice that seems a little redundant. like user agent vary is duplicated.

```
# Set header information for proxies 
Header append Vary User-Agent 

# Set header information for proxies 
Header append Vary User-Agent
```

---

Server fixed the retransmission and dup ack's a few days ago but lag in initial server response remains.

http://www.aboveallhouseplans.com/images/firstbyte001.jpg

http://www.aboveallhouseplans.com/images/firstbyte002.jpg

---

First byte of 600ms remains...

Comment: You need more data. Figure outthe ping time between `WebPageTest.org` and your web site. Get a packet capture on your server when the test is being conducted. Look at the times between events, and see if it matches the `WebPageTest.org` report. You need to know if the HTTP request is taking a long time to arrive or if your server is taking too long to generate a response. If the latter, you then need to profile your server.

Comment: wow... I'll do that. first I'll learn how. I'm sure it's not too hard. thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Thanks to Kevin who cleaned up my question.
@JXH I've tried to ping the test servers for webpagetest.org and they're behind a firewall. I take it from forum posts that they're target of a lot of DOS attacks. I'm adding traceroute test for my domain to the main question.

Comment: @ JXH, when I ping my server from my pc I get 38ms max 45ms average of 40ms.

Comment: This means it should only take about 70 ms to complete a 3-way TCP handshake. Next, find out time to first byte for request on your server, and time when you server sends the first byte of response, which you can find taking a packet capture (`tcpdump` or `tshark`). Analyze the capture with `wireshark`.

Comment: Well, I may be dense... none of the tcpdump commands are working in my console. looks like I need to learn more about terminal commands. I think I got tcpdump installed at least.

Comment: Ok I have ran a capture packet and opened it in wireshark. it's mostly green with 6 lines of black with red lettering. I take it that is bad.

Comment: I have no idea, I can't see what you see. Try following the links [here](http://ask.wireshark.org/questions/10166/online-tutorial-for-reading-packet-capture-files) to learn how to use wireshark.

Comment: You can get WebPageTest to capture the packets during the test, and then either download the pcap, or view it in CloudShark (be careful about uploading it to Cloudshark if it contains private information).  WPT also allows you to do a traceroute from their agents.  Add response time to you Apache Logs it's a quick way of working out if the HTTP server is slow.

Comment: That's a lot of info for one paragraph... I'll digest and get back to you. thanks.